# XCTestExpectation just hangs

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase, xctestexpectation

I have no idea what's going on. I'm using an `expectation` in my test and it will not timeout. I've removed so much of my test that now I'm just left with:

```
func testItem() {
    let expec = expectation(description: "expection")
    wait(for: [expec], timeout: 3.0)
}
```

And it won't fail. It just hangs. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `XCTestExpectation(description:)` instead of `expectation(description:)`? I suspect the problem might be that you add `expec` to `self.expectations`, for which you should wait with `waitForExpectations` instead of `wait(for:)`

Comment: @DávidPásztor your suggestion worked! I always thought they were interchangeable. Anways, feel free to stick it in as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `XCTestCase.expectation(description:)`, which adds the returned `XCTestExpectation` to `self.expectations`, you should use `waitForExpectations` instead of `wait(for:)`.

When using `wait(for:)` you should be creating your expectations using  `XCTestExpectation(description:)`.